# template language function 'slice' expects its first parameter to be of type string in logicapps Variables

Tags: arrays, json, slice, extract, azure-logic-apps

I have a requirement to slice "Dev" from below variable vmName in Azure logicapp

variable information :

- Name : vmName
- Type : String
- Value : Dev-Testing-2

When i tried with below approach/expression :

```
slice(split(variables('dsvmName'),'-'),1)
```

error : The template language function 'slice' expects its first parameter to be of type string. The provided value is of type 'Array'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#slice for usage details.'.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (untested) ...

```
split(variables('dsvmName'),'-')?[0]
```

That will retrieve the first item in the array when you split it by a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results and followed below process:

Firstly, I have taken a http trigger and then initialized as below:
[image]

Then, again I initialized as below:

```
indexOf(variables('vmName'), '-')
```

[image]

Then again initialized as below to get output:

`substring(variables('vmName'),0, int(variables('emo')))`

[image]

Output:

[image]

[image]